# android-x86 on vmware ext4-fs corrupt

Tags: android-x86

I've installed Android-x86 7.1-RC1 Nougat VM image for VMWARE but I often get this error and so I have to restore the original image of the vm from scratch.

[image: error]
Is there a command I can use to solve this problem and continue booting the system?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when installing Android-x86 8.1-RC2 on my physical laptop.
I'm not so sure if it's a bug or something but it looks like for some reason the system has been shut down uncleanly and the filesystem is corrupted.
I had to run `sudo fsck.ext4 -vy /dev/sdaX` from a linux live cd each time I had this error.
I know it's tedious and umpratical. I hope somebody will come up with a better solution.